# Cannot read property 'elements' Stripe woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I have a problem with stripe in checkout page wordpress.

when i want to checkout my order i see this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (stripe.min.js?ver=4.1.13:1)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

and the form is disactivated :

[image]

but when i deactivate dokan or dokan pro plugin stripe is working without problem.

can you help me please !

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: i dont modify any code of stripe or dokan or dokan pro is the same code, but not working

Comment: looks like a conflict between plugins

Answer (score 2):

I have an alternate solution. I got the same problem because I have woocommerce gateway stripe and dokan plugin both.

> Go to woocommerce -> setting and then Payments tab.
> select "Enable Payment Request Buttons (Apple Pay/Chrome Payment Request API) option to enable it.

Then you will not get such an error on the checkout page.

If you don't want the payment request button then you can hide the payment request button on the product page by the below code to your active theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_hide_payment_request_on_product_page', '__return_true');
```

You can hide the payment request button from the cart page by the below code to your active theme's functions.php file.

```
function remove_stripe_apple_pay_button_on_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_html' ), 1 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_separator_html' ), 2 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_stripe_apple_pay_button_on_cart', 1 );
```

If you want to show the payment request button on the checkout page then add the below code to your active theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_show_payment_request_on_checkout', '__return_true');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is simply to delete the folder called `woocommerce-gateway-stripe` from your plugins. Download the Latest plugin from https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/ and then Install it.